# Verify if email sender has permission to send to a certain address

Tags: arrays, perl, policy, qmail, mail-sender

I am forced to implement a sender policy in qmail.

I have a file describing the policies:

```
User1@domain1.com:*@domain1.com,x@Domain2.COM,y@DOMAIN.com
user2@domain1.com:*@*
USER3@domain1.com:
```

This file describes the following situation:

```
user1@domain1.com can send messages to anyone having the address defined on domain1.com, to x@domain2.com and to y@domain.com
user2@domain1.com can send messages to anyone
user3@domain1.com can not send messages at all
```

The letter case should be ignored.

I have to implement those restrictions in qmail, using qmailqueue and PERL (Mail::Qmail::Queue::Message) but I have no knowledge of PERL at all.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I have no knowledge of PERL at all.

Then the solution is

- to hire someone who does, or
- to start learning. See [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info).

(As an aside, the language is called *Perl*, and the interpreter used to run Perl programs is called *perl*. Other capitalizations are a bit frowned upon).

---

Should you decide to try solving this problem on your own, here are a few pointers:

The problem can be decomposed into subproblems:

- Parsing the rule file. This is rather easy with the `split` function.

  The function takes zero to three arguments: regex, string, limit. If the limit is omitted, the number of resulting fragments is arbitrary. If the string is omitted, then the `$_` special variable is used. If the regex is omitted, it will be treated as if the special value `" "` was given: Splits on all whitespace, and removes leading whitespace.

  To parse a line, the following will have to be done:

  - Removing the trailing newline with `chomp`,
  - Splitting the line on `:` into sender and rule string, with at most two fragments,
  - Splitting the rule string on `,` into single rules,
  - Splitting each rule at `@` into user and domain part.

  The rules can then be saved in a database or a Perl data structure.
- Matching rules given a pair of sender and receiver addresses. In case of a database, this could be done with a nice SQL query. In case of a Perl data structure, you would:

  - retrieve all rules for the sender's address
  - Iterate through all rules: Match the user and domain parts and return true once both match.
  - Else, return false

  Matching a rule against an address will first check if the rule part (user/domain) is a `*`. Else, the parts are tested for equality. Both the user and domain part have to match for the whole rule to match.
- Choosing a good Perl data structure: To make our life easy, all email addresses and rules are only handled in their normalized form. This means e.g. lowercase. For each object in the above algorithm, one could define a seperate class. This is probably undesirable. Instead,

  - Each rule can be represented as a 2-valued array reference
  - The rule list for a sender could be represented as an array reference of rules.
  - The association between the sender address and receiver rules can be made through a hash.

---

### Code examples

#### Parsing a line

where the line is given in `$_`, and a hashref `$rules_for_sender` is in scope

```
chomp;
my ($sender, $rules) = map lc, split /:/, $_, 2;
my @rules = map [split /@/], split /,/, $rules;
$rules_for_sender->{$sender} = \@rules;
```

#### Iterating through all rules for a sender

```
for my $rule (@{ $rules->{$sender} } {
  my ($rule_user, $rule_domain) = @$rule;
  ...; # do stuff here
}
```

#### The rest…

…is almost trivial if you remember

- to normalize correctly,
- that `use strict; use warnings;` helps you find many errors, and
- that string comparision is done with the `eq` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I wrote it in a shell script (I had only one day to make it running). I already started deciphering Perl.